# phpldapadmin interface won't produce Samba SID number

Tags: ldap

I am trying to create a new user group within the `phpldapadmin` interface. Under the Samba SID entry it gives me two boxes side by seide with the following:

```
=php.PickList(/;(&(objectClass=sambaDomain));sambaSID;%sambaSID% (%sambaDomainName%));;;;sambaDomainName
```

and

```
NO Methods: drawAttributeHelperAttribute|drawAttributeHelper
```

there might be more to the second box, but that's all that fits in it. Normally this field should generate a SID on its own but seems to somehow fail.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with the version 1.2.0.5. There is a mistake on the template used to create the Samba Group.

#### To correct the problem do

Access the prompt as root:

```
cd /etc/phpldapadmin/templates/creation
```

#### edit the file 'sambaGroupMapping.xml'

Find the line bellow in bold:

```
<attribute id="sambaSID">
  <display>Samba SID</display>
  <helper>
    <id>sidsuffix</id>
    <value><![CDATA[=php.GetNextNumber(/;gidNumber;false;(&(objectClass=sambaDomain)(sambaDomainName=mysambadomain));*2,+1000)]]></value>
  </helper>
  <order>4</order>
  <post>=php.Join(-;%sambaSID%,%sidsuffix%)</post>
  <page>1</page>
  **<value><![CDATA[=php.PickList(/;(&(objectClass=sambaDomain));sambaSID;%sambaSID% (%sambaDomainName%));;;;sambaDomainName]]></value>**
</attribute>
```

And replace for that:

```
<value><![CDATA[=php.PickList(/;(&(objectClass=sambaDomain));sambaSID;%sambaSID% (%sambaDomainName%);;;;sambaDomainName**)**]]></value>
```

The last parenthesis was type in wrong place. After changed that, the problem had solved.